# How can I GROUP BY and Select and Aggregate function and a None Aggregate function in a single SQL query?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table (**table1**) with columns(**Tenant_Name**, **Reading_Date**, **Previous_Unit**, **Current_Unit**, **Consumption**, in my Access database which i want  to Grouped out Rows base on  **Tenant_Name** and recent **Reading_Date** and at the same time selecting **Previous_Unit** and '**Consumption**' which aren't aggregate functions.

In essence, I actually want to GROUP BY and combine an aggregate function and a none aggregate function. I have done all i could but still not get a solution. I will appreciate if someone can help me out. below is the table and exactly what i want.

Table1

```
   ID |Tenant_Name |  Reading_Date | Previous_Unit |  Current_Unit | Consumption
  ****|************|***************|***************|***************|************
   1  |    Rex     |  14/9/2020    |      100      |       450     |    250     
   2  |    Owen    |  18/9/2020    |      30       |       207     |    177     
   3  |    Chris   |  17/8/2020    |      105      |       401     |    396 
   4  |    Mike    |  24/12/2020   |      90       |       104     |    14   
   5  |    Rex     |  24/2/2021    |      450      |       701     |    251
   6  |    Chris   |  10/2/2021    |      401      |       708     |    307
   7  |    Owen    |  12/2/2021    |      207      |       480     |    277
   8  |    Neil    |  18/12/2020   |      50       |       300     |    250
```

This is exactly the result I want. Please help a brother!

```
   ID |Tenant_Name |  Reading_Date | Previous_Unit |  Current_Unit | Consumption
   ***|************|***************|***************|***************|************
    1 |     Rex    |   24/2/2021   |      450      |       701     |    251
    2 |     Owen   |   12/2/2021   |      207      |       480     |    277
    3 |     Chris  |   10/2/2021   |      401      |       708     |    307
    4 |     Mike   |   24/12/2020  |      90       |       104     |    14
    8 |     Neil   |   18/12/2020  |      50       |       300     |    250
```

Comment: which database you are using?

Comment: Hi @PrakharGupta I am Using Access database

Comment: Why do you expect id=1 for Rex? This is not the id with the latest Reading_Date for Rex.

Comment: Also, what is the data type of Reading_Date?

Comment: Hi @forpas I am not so concerned at the ID. the 'Reading_Date data type is datetime.

Comment: i problem is i want to group the duplicated rows, amongst the duplicated rows, i want to select only the rows with recent **Reading_Date**. i intent to group these rows by 'Tenant_Name'

Comment: @Chris76 since you don't want to perform any aggregation then you don't need `group by`. You just need for each name the row with the latest date. Check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT t1.* FROM Table1 AS t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM Table1 AS t2
  WHERE t2.Tenant_Name = t1.Tenant_Name
    AND t2.Reading_Date > t1.Reading_Date
)
```

Comment: Oh wow! actually @forpas, this query solve the problem. but i needed aggregated function on "Reading_Date" that is MAX(Reading_Date)

Comment: @Chris76 this query returns the max `Reading_Date` with `NOT EXISTS`, without using the `MAX()` aggregate function.

Comment: this solved my problem bro. you're a life saver. what if  t2.Reading_Date = t1.Reading_Date, and i want to select just one out of the two bro. what SQL statement can i use to archive this

Comment: @Chris76 if you mean that there may exist 2 rows for a Tenant_Name with the same max  Reading_Date and you want only 1 of the rows then you could pick the one with the greatest ID. The WHERE clause inside the NOT EXISTS subquery should be: `WHERE (t2.Tenant_Name = t1.Tenant_Name) AND (t2.Reading_Date > t1.Reading_Date OR (t2.Reading_Date = t1.Reading_Date AND t2.ID > t1.ID))`

Comment: Hi @forpas, accept greetings from my end. hope you been doing all good.

Comment: I thought it wise to Normalize my  access database. so now, I wish to INNER JOIN two tables to my existing sql query. the two tables are "Tenants" and "Taxes_Tariff" which all contain "Tenant ID". here is the query. SELECT BillSummary1.*
FROM BillSummary AS BillSummary1
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( 
SELECT 1 FROM BillSummary AS BillSummary2
WHERE (BillSummary2.[Tenant Name] = BillSummary1.[Tenant Name])
AND (BillSummary2.[Current Reading Date] > BillSummary1.[Current Reading Date]
OR   (BillSummary2.[Tenant Name] = BillSummary1.[Tenant Name])
AND BillSummary2.ID > BillSummary1.ID)
)

Comment: @Chris76 the questions are not asked in the comments section. Start a new thread where you ask your question.

Comment: Hi @forpas, I already did so. this is the link https://stackoverflow.com/q/67119504/15284091

Answer (score 1):

If you want the most recent row for each `name` (which is how I interpret the question), you can use a correlated subquery:

```
select t1.*
from table1 as t1
where t1.reading_date = (select max(tt1.reading_date)
                         from table1 as tt1
                         where tt1.Tenant_Name = t1.Tenant_Name
                        );
```

The only difference from your results (that I can tell) is the `id` column.  I don't know if that is important.

Comment: This will cause issue when maximum value of reading date for 1 name is not the maximum for other name.

Comment: @PrakharGupta . . . This returns the latest row for each name, based on the reading date for that name.  That appears to be what the OP wants.

Comment: Example - 
(Name   Reading_Date)-
(Alex     2021-02-20)
(Alex     2021-01-10)
(Ben     2021-02-20)
(Ben    2021-02-21)

In above case 1st and 4th row must be part of output but your query will give 1st,3rd and 4th row as output

Comment: I executed this one also but i didnt get the values of columns

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE (tenant_name,reading_date) IN (SELECT tenant_name, MAX(reading_date) FROM table1 GROUP BY tenant_name);
```

Comment: What's the issue you are getting ?

Comment: I just added parenthesis. Can you check once?

Comment: this is the error i got when i tried to execute the query. I am using MS Access database.

Comment: "You have written a subquery that can return more than one field without using the EXISTS reserved word in the main query's FROM clause. Revise the SELECT statement of the subquery to request only one field. (Error 3306)"

Comment: is there a means on this platform where i can sent you the database file for you to execute the query yourself?

Comment: It is multiple row subquery that's why I have used IN operator and we can specify multiple fields in IN clause

Comment: Please tell me the issue you are getting ?

Comment: "You have written a subquery that can return more than one field without using the EXISTS reserved word in the main query's FROM clause. Revise the SELECT statement of the subquery to request only one field. (Error 3306)"

Comment: that is the error i get. you can check my second to last message

Comment: I just executed on mysql and it is working fine.

Comment: I didn't think that Access SQL supported that column-set syntax?  (ie, `(col11, ...) = (col21, ...)`  Pretty sure you have to use the more cumbersome EXISTS subquery syntax on Access.

Comment: @PrakharGupta  Access SQL is slightly more restrictive than MySql and doesn't support some of the newer SQL syntax features.

Comment: @RBarryYoung are insinuating i should use SQL SERVER Database or Mysql file?

Comment: @Chris76 No, not al all.  Just use the older EXISTS syntax, or the "=" syntax that Gordon posted.  Column-sets are pretty new, we had to always use EXISTS or other tricks for this for many, many years.  It's just a bit more work on the coder's part.  (Honestly, I still use EXISTS all the time out of habit anyway, partly because EXISTS is so much more general than the other approaches)

Comment: There *are* many possible good reasons to use a full DBMS like MySql or SQL Server over MS Access (in exchange for possibly higher support and/or license costs), but simplifying this one query isn't one of them.

Comment: ok @RBarryYoung still I am unable to get a solution bro. :)

Comment: @Chris76 AFAIK, Gordon's corrected query should work.  I am happy to post an EXISTS version, though I didn't think that it was necessary.