# How can add "INNER JOIN" to an existing "NOT EXIST" Query?. The query is in the description below

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, ms-access

I have an existing Ms Access query which works just fine as per my need, now I want to join another two tables (**"Taxes_Tariffs"** and **"complaints"**) Which all have a common column **"Tenant_ID"** and **Bill_#**

Can someone help me out with the way forward to include this additional functionality to the existing query below?
I will highly appreciate for your contributionS. Thanks

```
SELECT BillSummary1.*
FROM BillSummary AS BillSummary1
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( 
SELECT 1 FROM BillSummary AS BillSummary2
WHERE (BillSummary2.[Tenant Name] = BillSummary1.[Tenant Name])
AND (BillSummary2.[Current Reading Date] > BillSummary1.[Current Reading Date]
OR   (BillSummary2.[Tenant Name] = BillSummary1.[Tenant Name])
AND BillSummary2.ID > BillSummary1.ID)
)
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be quite helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You may add the `inner join` in the `not exist` just after `BillSummary2` eg.

```sql
SELECT BillSummary1.*
FROM BillSummary AS BillSummary1
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( 
SELECT 1 FROM BillSummary AS BillSummary2

INNER JOIN
    Taxes_Tariffs ON Taxes_Tariffs.Tenant_ID = BillSummary2.Tenant_ID AND
                     Taxes_Tariffs.Bill_NO =  BillSummary2.Bill_NO
INNER JOIN
    complaints ON complaints.Tenant_ID = BillSummary2.Tenant_ID AND
                     complaints.Bill_NO =  BillSummary2.Bill_NO

WHERE (BillSummary2.[Tenant Name] = BillSummary1.[Tenant Name])
AND (BillSummary2.[Current Reading Date] > BillSummary1.[Current Reading Date]
OR   (BillSummary2.[Tenant Name] = BillSummary1.[Tenant Name])
AND BillSummary2.ID > BillSummary1.ID)
)
```

if you would like to include these columns in your initial select you may use the following:

```sql
SELECT 
    BillSummary1.*,
    Taxes_Tariffs.*,
     complaints.*
FROM BillSummary AS BillSummary1
INNER JOIN
    Taxes_Tariffs ON Taxes_Tariffs.Tenant_ID = BillSummary1.Tenant_ID AND
                     Taxes_Tariffs.Bill_NO =  BillSummary1.Bill_NO
INNER JOIN
    complaints ON complaints.Tenant_ID = BillSummary1.Tenant_ID AND
                     complaints.Bill_NO =  BillSummary1.Bill_NO
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( 
SELECT 1 FROM BillSummary AS BillSummary2



WHERE (BillSummary2.[Tenant Name] = BillSummary1.[Tenant Name])
AND (BillSummary2.[Current Reading Date] > BillSummary1.[Current Reading Date]
OR   (BillSummary2.[Tenant Name] = BillSummary1.[Tenant Name])
AND BillSummary2.ID > BillSummary1.ID)
)
```

Comment: hi @ggordan. Thanks for your response. the first query works just as normal but the second query which i want to include the columns in my initial select would give me the error " The Microsoft Access Database engine does not recognize 'Taxes_Tariffs.* ' as a valid field name or expression.

Comment: seems more like the database engine does not recognize the second select "Taxes_Tariffs" as a table